# How to make document.bgcolor to work?

Tags: javascript

Following is the code which I have tried

What I want is on after 3 seconds the documents `bgcolor` to change

I have used `document.bgcolor` and its not working as it always returns `black`

```
 var A = new Array("0", "1", "2");
    var B = 0;
    var C = 3;

    function D() {

        if (document.images) {
            B++;
            if (B == C) {

                B = 0;
            }
            document.bgColor = A[B];
            setTimeout("D()", 3 * 1000);
        }
    }


    window.onload = function () {

        D();
    }
```

Comment: Is this script created by an old Photoshop or sth? `bgColor` has been deprecated for a while ago, maybe even obsoleted in some browsers. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need a color starting with "#". for example "#123456" or "#123". As far as I can see you just set the color to "1", "2" or "3".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of these:

```
var A = new Array("0", "1", "2");
```

Try this:

```
var A = new Array("black", "white", "blue");
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/gSCEc/

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
document.bgColor = A[B];
```

with

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = A[B];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to set background colour is:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = somecolour;
```

`document.bgColor` hasn't been around since HTML 3.2.

Note that the colour MUST be a valid CSS colour. This means it can be:

- A 24-bit colour in the form #RRGGBB, each letter standing for a hexadecimal digit,
- A 12-bit colour in the form #RGB, again each letter stands for a hex digit,
- A 24-bit colour of the form `rgb( R, G, B)` this time each letter stands for a number between 0 and 255,
- A 32-bit colour of the form `rgba( R, G, B, A)` with R,G,B standing for numbers between 0 and 255, and A is a decimal number between 0 (transparent) and 1 (opaque).
- A colour name. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) for a complete list.

Therefore, your strings `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"` will not do.

Try something like this:

```
(function() {
    var colours = ["#ff8080","#80ff80","#8080ff"],
        colcount = colours.length, // cache for efficiency reasons
        currentcolour = 0; // adjust if you want to start at a different one
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colours[currentcolour];
    setInterval(function() {
        currentcolour = (currentcolour+1) % colcount;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colours[currentcolour];
    },3000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using javascript and hexadecimal color codes? A really good website to see visually hoe hex translates to color is rapidtables.com

```
<html>
<head><head/>
<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    document.bgColor='#2a2a2a';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```